# Salesforce C# web service - query failing because of a quote in persons name

Tags: query, c#

I need some help with a Salesforce C# query. I have a C# web application that interfaces with a Salesforce instance and part of that does a query on a persons name that is stored in Salesforce, if we pass a name with a single quote (') in it to the query function, it breaks saying MALFORMED QUERY and references the part right after the single quote.

Below is the code. If you have any fixes please let me know! I've tried replacing the ' with \' and I've tried '' - nothing works. Same error everytime. If the name passed to the query doesn't have a quote in it, it works fine and returns desired person.

```
_sforceService.query("SELECT Patient_ID__c, Id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = '" + contactToCheckAgainst.FirstName + "' AND LastName = '" + contactToCheckAgainst.LastName + "' AND Birthdate = " + sqlFormattedDate + " AND Mailing_Postal_Code__c = '" + contactToCheckAgainst.Mailing_Postal_Code__c + "'");
```

Comment: `String.escapeSingleQuotes(str)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Quoted String Escape Sequences](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm), which basically states that you need to use `\` before any quote, double-quote, or backslash, and optionally before an underscore or percent sign when using LIKE.

Keep in mind that `\` is an escape character in C# (and other languages), so you usually need to have *two* backslashes in your source code.

```
contactToCheckAgainst.LastName = contactToCheckAgainst.LastName.Replace("'", "\\'");
```

Comment: You rock my socks off buddy!!! Totally worked, thank you so much!